# Can't extract key from Map

Tags: clojure

I'm hitting an API that returns some json that I am trying to parse. I look a the keys of the returned parsed values and it says that it has a key "id", but when I try to get the id from the map, I get nothing back.

E.g.:

```
(require '[clj-http.client :as client]
         '[cheshire.core :refer :all])

(def app-url "http://myapp.com/api/endpoint")
(defn get-application-ids [] (parse-string (:body (client/get app-url))))

(defn -main [] (println (map :id  (get-application-ids))))
```

This returns `(nil nil nil)`. Which, AFAIKT, it shouldn't - instead it should return the value of the :id field, which is not null.

Helpful facts:

1. When I run `(map keys (get-application-ids))` to find the keys of the returned structure, I get `((id name attempts) (id name attempts) (id name attempts))`.
2. `(type (get-application-ids))` returns `clojure.lang.LazySeq`
3. `(map type (get-application-ids))` returns `(clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap)`
4. `(println (get-application-ids))` returns (one example of the three returned):

```
({id application_1595586907236_1211, name myname, attempts [{appSparkVersion 2.4.0-cdh6.1.0, lastUpdated 2020-07-26T20:18:47.088GMT, completed true, lastUpdatedEpoch 1595794727088, sparkUser super, endTimeEpoch 1595794726804, startTime 2020-07-26T20:04:05.998GMT, attemptId 1, duration 880806, endTime 2020-07-26T20:18:46.804GMT, startTimeEpoch 1595793845998}]})
```

Everything about this tells me that `(map :id  (get-application-ids))` should return the value of the id field, but it doesn't. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using `cheshire.core/parse-string`.  This will return string keys, not keywords.  See [this example](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire#decoding).

So, it appears that your key is the string `"id"`, not the keyword `:id`.  To verify this theory, try putting in the debugging statement:

```
(prn (:body (client/get app-url)))
```

To ask Cheshire to convert map keys from strings to keywords, use the form

```
(parse-string <json-src> true)  ; `true` => output keyword keys
```

See also [this list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).  Especially study the Clojure CheatSheet daily.

Comment: I'm suspecting the same issue. I would like to get the type of "id". @Logister, you can get that with the command `(type (first (first (map keys (get-application-ids)))))`